# Duplicating an image in each container during iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'd like to clone each section's `bgimage` under the section title without affecting the original image.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="imagepath_1.jpg" alt="" />
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="imagepath_2.jpg" alt="" />
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="imagepath_3.jpg" alt="" />
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And my code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.section').each( function (index, data) {    
        $(this).find('img.bgimage').first().clone().appendTo('.section h2').first();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your code is that `appendTo` adds a child element to a container. What you really want is `insertAfter`.

Another problem is that you're not referring to each section in the `each` function. You should use the second function parameter.

Here is a solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.section').each(function (index, section) {    
    var image = $(section).find('img.bgimage').first(),
        title = $(section).find('h2').first();
    image.clone().insertAfter(title);
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery.com/i/feature-sprites.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <img class="bgimage" src="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/jq-nav-icons.png" alt="" />
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <!--clone goes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Please push the button to accept my answer (and upvote it as well, if you haven't already).